# Solution to Stock Price SDE with mean reversion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma, mean-reversion, sde

Suppose $S_t$ follows the process (notice the $S_t$ term in the diffusion part):

$$ S_t := S_0 + \int_{h=t_0}^{h=t}\alpha(\mu -S_h)dh + \int_{h=t_0}^{h=t}\sigma S_h dW(h) $$.

I actually don't know how to solve the above SDE using Ito's lemma. I tried the following:

(i) $F(S_t) := ln(S_t)$. This produces:

$$ F(S_t) := F(S_0) + \int_{h=t_0}^{h=t} \left( \frac{1}{S_h}\alpha\mu -\alpha \right) dh + \int_{h=t_0}^{h=t}\sigma dW(h) $$.

Which I wouldn't know how to continue solving.

I also tried $F(S_t, t) := S_t - \alpha \mu t $, which also didn't lead anywhere, and of course I tried $F(S_t,t)=S_te^{\alpha t}$, which unfortunately leaves the stochastic term $S_h$ in the diffusion integral.

How does one actually solve the above SDE? It looks very similar to the Orsntein-Uhlenbeck process, but the additional term $S_h$ in the diffusion integral is the difference maker. I am sure there must be some smart substitution $F(S_t)$ that we can apply Ito's lemma to and simplify the SDE: I just can't think of it.

Comment: Note that $dS_t = \alpha(\mu-S_t)dt + \sigma S_t dW_t$. Try to use Ito's lemma for $d\left(e^{\alpha t }S_t \right)$.

Comment: @Gordon: thank you: I did try that, which leads to: $$S_te^{\alpha t} = S_0 + \int_{h=t_0}^{h=t}e^{\alpha h} \alpha \mu dh + \int_{h=t_0}^{h=t}e^{\alpha h} \sigma S_h dW_h$$. Where do we go from here, i.e. does the Stochastic integral simplify any further?

Comment: I missed the $S_t$ in the diffusion part. Please try $d\left(e^{(\alpha+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t-\sigma W_t} S_t \right)$. See also [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/50485/solve-the-following-sde-mathrmdx-t-ab-x-t-mathrmdt-c-x-t-mat/50488#50488).

Comment: @Gordon: you are a legend. You can probably mark my question as a duplicate then...

Comment: Yeh, that answers it.